# Google VM / Python Requests Network Issues on "heavy-ish" volume

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

In my .py program on Google's VM, when I send a lot of requests at the same time, I get this kind of response. I do not believe this is a problem with the server I am trying to access because all network requests will fail at the same from `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:` to `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ratesapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/latest?base=USD`. (Of course, it could be possible each failed for its own reason independently). Note the first one is simply a Google Storage API, which I don't believe has any limits (given I pay for it). I also have the VM and the storage in the same region so there should be very little if any network issues. Finally, my egress is only 1mb/s and ingress is 20mb/s, which doesn't seem very high.

It's hard to figure out the problem, because the problem doesn't always occur.

Are there other constraints I am not considering? Are there Google Storage quotas, or VM quotas I'm not considering? Or are there Python-related bottlenecks I am not considering?

Update: also noticed that my memory usage was 80%+, but can't tell which one is the cause

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd5c45e4320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ratesapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/latest?base=USD (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd5c45e4320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pyscripts/python2/sommpyscripts/_findCurrency.py", line 269, in findCurrency
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ratesapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/latest?base=USD (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd5c45e4320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))"
```

Comment: 1) High CPU utilization will cause networking to intermittently fail. 2) What service and instance size are you using? 3) Your error is related to DNS name resolution. You might be hammering the DNS server and get blocked, CPU utilization is too high, defects in your code, etc. 4) Suggestion, try a larger instance size to bring CPU down to 50% or less. 5) Edit your question with a code that matches the error and more details on the service you are using.

Comment: Did you try a larger VM with more RAM & CPU ? If so does the issue persists (can you post cpu & ram usage) ?

Comment: Thank you for both of your comments, this is what I will try and report back

Answer (score 0):

The answers in the comments were correct. I believe limits in the CPU, RAM as well as Hard Drive were causing the issues. Between those three, I believe CPU is a less likely explanation as we've hit 100% CPU a few times and did not see those messages whereas we saw those messages a lot more when RAM and Hard Drive were near 100%.